# why xgboost calculate the gradient only for n_estimators rounds?

Tags: xgboost, lightgbm

Here, n_estimators means the number of trees（week learners）in xgboost. I define a custom objective functions where I have to calculate the first and second order gradients. And I also add a print function in the custom objective functions, so that I can count the numbers of the custom objective functions's being called (invoked). Finally, I find the function is called by only n_estimators times.

Previously, I thought the custom objective functions should be called when doing a leaf split, and even one tree can have many leaf splits. So now I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

In both XGBoost and LightGBM, gradients are computed once at the beginning of each boosting round.

Each tree is then built to try to explain the gradient based on candidate feature splits. You can think of this as sort of like, "each tree is a decision tree trained to predict the *residuals* of the model so far", but where the values of "residual" are determined by the chosen objective function. That is why the gradients don't need to be re-computed every time a node is added to one of the model's trees.

### Example

Here is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the behavior you've asked about. I ran this code today on macOS with Python 3.9.7, using `lightgbm==3.3.2` and `xgboost==1.5.0` from conda-forge.

I provided `lightgbm` and `xgboost` examples since the original post had both of those tags.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from typing import Tuple, Union

COUNTER = 0

def _objective_least_squares(
    y_pred: np.ndarray,
    train_data: Union[lgb.Dataset, xgb.DMatrix]
) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    global COUNTER
    print(f"iteration: {COUNTER}")
    y_true = train_data.get_label()
    grad = y_pred - y_true
    hess = np.ones(len(y_true))
    COUNTER += 1
    return grad, hess

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1_000, n_features=10, n_informative=8, random_state=708)

#--- xgboost example ---#
COUNTER = 0
xgb_dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data=X, label=y)
xgb_model = xgb.train(
    params={'tree_method': 'hist', 'verbosity': 0},
    dtrain=xgb_dtrain,
    num_boost_round=10,
    obj=_objective_least_squares
)
print(f"Model has {len(xgb_model.trees_to_dataframe())} total tree nodes")

#--- lightgbm example ---#
COUNTER = 0
lgb_dtrain = lgb.Dataset(data=X, label=y)
lgb_model = lgb.train(
    params={'seed': 1994, 'verbosity': -1},
    train_set=lgb_dtrain,
    num_boost_round=10,
    fobj=_objective_least_squares
)
print(f"Model has {len(lgb_model.trees_to_dataframe())} total tree nodes")
```

Both examples show the behavior reported in the original post...the objective function is evaluated once per iteration, not once per tree node.

```
iteration: 0
iteration: 1
iteration: 2
iteration: 3
iteration: 4
iteration: 5
iteration: 6
iteration: 7
iteration: 8
iteration: 9
```

The `print()` statements added after training confirm that the models produced in this example have more than 10 total tree nodes, just to confirm that this is an accurate way to show how often the objective function is called.

```
# xgboost example
Model has 1100 total tree nodes

# lightgbm example
Model has 610 total tree nodes
```